# Find the area $x$ of the quadrilateral below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In the figure, $ABCD$ is a square. If MN is perpendicular to $PQ$ and $P$ is any point, calculate $x$.(Answer:$1u^2$)
[image]

$\angle ANM \cong \angle NMC\\
\angle NMB \cong \angle MND$

$MN$ is common side

$$AB=CD$$

Is this enough to say that the two quadrilaterals are congruent?

Comment: Why are there two different points labelled $P$?

Comment: @TedShifrin probably misprint

Comment: HINT: Show that $AP=ND=QC=MB$.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Could you demonstrate this equality?

Comment: @TedShifrin The idea of the problem is to use plane geometry

Comment: You should remove your acceptance of my answer. It is not complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P'\in\overline{CD}$ be chosen so that $\overline{PP'}$ is parallel to $\overline{AD}$, and let $N'\in\overline{BC}$ be chosen so that $\overline{NN'}$ is parallel to $\overline{CD}$. Because $\overline{PQ}$ and $\overline{MN}$ are perpendicular, we see that $\angle QPP'\cong\angle MNN'$ and so $\triangle PP'Q\cong \triangle NN'M$. Thus, $P'Q = N'M$.

The areas of trapezoids $ADQP$ and $NDCM$ are equal, and so, since they have equal heights, $AP + DQ = ND + CM$. This means that $2AP + P'Q = 2ND + N'M$, and so $AP=ND$. Similarly, the areas of trapezoids $BPQC$ and $BANM$ are equal, and so $QC=MB$.  However, I cannot continue at this stage.

Comment: Can you explain : $AP+DQ=ND+CM(Ok) \implies \underbrace{2AP+P'Q=2ND+N'M}$

Comment: @petaarantes $DQ=AP'+P'Q=AP+P'Q$ and so on.

Comment: @ACB  Thanks.................

Comment: The argument for $AP=ND$ is clear. So far we are using the fact that the trapezoid areas $[ADQP]$ and $[DCMN]$ are equal, both $u^2+u^2$. Now which further "similar argument" allows as to continue with $AP=QC$ and/or $ND=QC$? Please mention those trapezoids by their name.

Comment: You are correct that my proof is incomplete.  I can deduce that $AP=ND$ and $QC=MB$, but not the equality of these two pairs. I withdraw my proof.

Answer (score 3):

The right angles make the quad. PMCQ cyclic. Then, $\angle PMC= \angle PQD$. Therefore, quad. PMCQ and quad. PQDN are equi-angular.

[image]

In addition, 'the two quadrilaterals are equal in area' implies they are congruent.

Then, PM of quad. PMCQ = PQ of quad PQDN and PQ of quad. PMCQ = PN of quad. PQDN. Therefore, PM = PQ = PN. (*)

The same logic extends to the third.

The logic of (*) plus the fourth quadrilateral is equi-angular should be enough to show that those four quadrilaterals are equal in area.

Comment: A square and a random rectangle are also equi-angular, are they also similar?

Comment: I agree with Dan. The fact that they are equiangular and have the same area does not guarantee that they are congruent.EX: Square (4x4) and a rectangle (8x2)

Comment: @dan_fulea  Have an idea for the solution?

Comment: @dan_fulea I think your "rectangle-square" is an example for a particular case. Other than that I hope there is no other counter example.

Comment: Well, it is simple to construct also other types of equiangular shapes that are not similar. Start for instance in your picture with the quadrilateral $PQCM$. Now take the line $PQ$, say, and move it parallely to itself to a position $P'Q'$ so that for instance $Q'$ is very close to $C$. It is clear that the angles are preserved by the movement, but the new shape $P'Q'CM$ has a bigger $P'Q'$ and a smaller $Q'C$ compared to $PQ$ and $QC$, a proportionality of sides is excluded. One can imagine many types of such sliding moves...

Comment: @dan_fulea I see what you mean. I will delete the deduction of saying that they will be similar.

Answer (score 2):

We can and do assume that the side of the square is one. Let us fix the position of $MN$, as shown in the picture below, and denote by $a,b$ the lengths of the segments $ND$ an $MC$.

[image: square with a fixed segment MN and a sliding line PQ perpendicular on MN]

We are searching first for a position of the segment $PQ$, with $PQ\perp MN$,
and

- with the equality of the areas $[PANR]$, and $[QCMR]$, denote by $U$ their common value,
- or equivalently (after adding $[RNDQ]$ to both) with the equality of the areas $[PADQ]$, and $[MNDC]$.

Since $[MNDC]$ is fixed, and the slide of a line $PQ$ "downwards",
parallel to itself on a direction perpendicular to $MN$, is a continuous movement cutting more and more from $[PADQ]$, the position of $PQ$ is unique. For short, the area $[PADQ]$ is a decreasing continuous function, seen as a function of $R\in[MN]$, which is moving from $M$ to $N$, and determining $PQ$. We know this position, it is realized by a $90^\circ$ rotation of $MN$ in the direction that brings the square $ABCD$ into $BCDA$, and $M$ in $Q$, $N$ in $P$, $MC=b$ in $QD=b$, $DN=a$ in $AP=a$.

So far we have arranged only that $U=[ANRP]=[CMRQ]$. Now we use the information that these areas are equal to $[DQRN]$. Again, fix the trapezium $APQD$ in sight, and let $R$ slide on $PQ$ from $P$ to $Q$, then draq the  perpendicular $RN$. It is clear that the area $[APRN]$ is a continuous, increasing function of $R$, so there exists a unique point $R$ realizing $[APRN]$ as the half of $[APQD]$. For this one point record the special value $AN:ND$. Now do the same with the trapezium $DNMC$, congruent with $APQD$. Consider again the point $R$ sliding on $NM$, it has by the same argument an existing unique position of $RQ$ to cut $[DNMC]$ in two equal areas, and the corresponding singular point $Q$ realizes the same proportion:
$$
\frac{AN}{ND}=
\frac{DQ}{QC}\ ,\qquad\text{ i.e. }\qquad
\frac{1-a}a=\frac{b}{1-b}\ .
$$
This gives $a=1-b$, so both $MN$ and $PQ$ are passing through the center of symmetry of the square. So the fourth piece $BPRM$ is congruent to the other three pieces, thus having the same area.

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

[image: Figure]

Let $O=MN\cap PQ$. Draw line segments $M'N'$  and $P'Q'$ through $O$ such that $M'N'\perp BC$, $P'Q'\perp AB$, $ON'=a$, $OQ'=b$, $\angle QOQ'=\theta$ as in the figure and let $k$ be the side length of the square. Adding and substracting the appropriate triangles after the rotation, we have
$$a(k-b)-\frac12(k-b)^2\tan\theta+\frac12a^2\tan\theta=1\tag1$$
$$ab-\frac12a^2\tan\theta+\frac12 b^2\tan\theta=1\tag2$$
$$b(k-a)-\frac12b^2\tan\theta+\frac12(k-a)^2\tan\theta=1\tag3$$
If $a=b$, then $a=b=1$, $k=2$ and we are done. Assume that $a\neq b$. From $(1),(2),(3)$ we can obtain
$$\tan\theta=\frac{b-a}{a+b-k}=\frac{2-2ab}{b^2-a^2}=\frac{4-k(a+b)}{k(b-a)}.$$
It is not so difficult to see that [$k$ must be $2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28b-a%29%2F%28a%2Bb-k%29%3D%282-2ab%29%2F%28b%5E2-a%5E2%29%3D%284-k%28a%2Bb%29%29%2F%28k%28b-a%29%29). But, then $a=b=1$ contradicting the assumption.